# Unique selection for multiple sections on Swift dynamic prototype cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a custom UITableView which contains several sections, each section represents an attribute and would bring only one value from its subordinated dynamic prototype cells at the end, just like the following:

> Attribute 1
>
> > choice 1    (check)
> >
> > choice 2
>
> Attribute 2
>
> > choice 1
> >
> > choice 2    (check)
> >
> > choice 3
>
> Attribute 3
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> value passed: [Attribute 1: choice 1, Attribute 2: choice 2, Attribute 3: ...]

My question is that how could I achieve the "unique selection" effect for each section just like a radio button on webpage when implementing "willSelectRowAtIndexPath" function? It first came up to my mind that I could set all the cells' accessoryType to .None under the corresponding section and then set the selected row's accessoryType to .Checkmark, however I couldn't reach "all the cells under the section" since they're dynamic cells. Anyone know about the way to get all the cells under one section, or have better ways to solve this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `indexPathsForSelectedRows` property of `UITableView` in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    if let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() {
        for selectedIndexPath in selectedIndexPaths {
            if indexPath.section == selectedIndexPath.section {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: I tried the function `indexPathsForSelectedRows`, but it gets only one indexPath even if I have two elements in that section... (selectedIndexPaths.count is always 1...)

Comment: Did you set `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection` to `YES`?

Comment: Finally I found that I have to put the above code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function. If I implement it in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`, `indexPathsForSelectedRows` will only get the previous selected rows instead of the one I want. Thanks for solving my problems anyway.